# Load Array Elements Using Function

Tags: c, arrays, function

I am trying to load elements into an array using a function but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I want to load elements from a data file until -1 is entered. Here is what I have and I don't know what to do from here.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*Function to scan in grades*/
int LoadArray (int grade[ ])
{
    int i = 0;
    while(scanf("%i", grade[i]) != -1) {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}


/*Main program*/
int main (void)
{
    int grade[200], count=0;
    /*Call function*/
    count = LoadArray(grade);
    printf("%i", count);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What problems do you have with the code you show? If you enable more warnings from the compiler, what does the compiler say (a good compiler *will* give you warnings about your code)? Oh, and I recommend you check e.g. [this `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), pay close attention to the argument types in the format-code table (this is *really* important!).

Comment: What makes you think that `scanf()` would return `-1` at some point? is t `EOF` that you mean?

Comment: while(scanf("%d", &grade[i])!=-1);

Comment: @milevyo: better without trailing `;`!

Comment: I'm getting a Segmentation fault (core dumped) once I try to run the program.

Comment: `while(i < 200 && 1==scanf("%i", &grade[i]) &&  grade[i] != -1) {`

Comment: Also you might want to take your compiler' s warnings serious.

Comment: If the grade array do not contain a -1 value, the loop goes beyond 199 and cause error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems.

1) You're missing an ampersand:

```
scanf("%i", &grade[i]);
```

you need to pass the *address* of the variable `scanf` should put the result in. You were passing the contents of `grade[i]` instead, and reading uninitialized memory is undefined behavior.

2) `scanf` doesn't return the value it read from `stdin`; you should compare the variable you read to -1. Also, it's bad practice to pass an array to a function but not its size, as then the function has no way of knowing how big the array is.

To sum up, the code with fixes looks like this:

```
/*Function to scan in grades*/
int LoadArray(int grade[], size_t gradeMaxCount)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        int tmp;
        if (i >= gradeMaxCount || scanf("%i", &tmp) != 1 || tmp == -1)
            break;

        grade[i++] = tmp;
    }

    return i;
}
```

Call the function like this:

```
count = LoadArray(grade, sizeof(grade) / sizeof(grade[0]));
```

Note that funny things will happen if `i` somehow becomes negative. You could make it `size_t` instead (this would also require you to change the function return type and print it using `%zu`), depending on how much of a purist you are.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Good catch, fixed.

Answer (score -1):

```
int LoadArray (int grade[ ])
{
    int i = 0;
    for(int j=0;j<200;j++){
       if((scanf("%d", grade+j) == -1) || (grade[j]==-1))
            break;

        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```